# flask-debugtoolbar ImportError: No module named flask_debugtoolbar

Tags: python, flask, pip, flask-sqlalchemy

I've done pip install flask-debugtoolbar but im still getting an import error

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension

# Create application
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.debug = True
toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Home!</a>'

import views
import models
```

Comment: which version of python?

Comment: 2.7 is the version

Comment: Can you post traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/namereg/run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "C:\namereg\app\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension
ImportError: No module named flask_debugtoolbar

Comment: try to install it again `pip install flask_debugtoolbar --upgrade`

Comment: Worked! Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Install**

`pip install flask_debugtoolbar --upgrade`

**body**

Add `body` to your html page:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return '<body><a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Home!</a></body>'

app.run()
```

Comment: For Ckan 2.8.2 it also works to do pip install -r dev-requirements.txt in the ckan root folder (when installed from source).